# Files displayed in lists

Tags: files, quicklists

How do I get files in Ubuntu 18.04 to display as lists? Have selected the various choices of info to be shown in lists, but cannot get the files to actually display as lists.

Answer (score 0):

Click on the icon at top-right next to the "search" button.

[image]